# Big Query is not executing successfully

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to executing the big Query using pyhton script on google clod platform.
I am trying to parameterize the values in the query. I am getting the value from the excel.

when i execute the query its not displaying any records. When i run the same query in Big query its executing with out any issue.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pandas import ExcelWriter

client=bigquery.Client()
#client.query(query_1)

df=pd.read_excel('16Junedata_03062020_80163767_action_03062020_80163767_2624_01.xls', sheet_name='Sheet4')
#newdf = df.fillna({'business_day':0,'zone_id':0,'site_id':0,'device_id':0})
newdf = df.fillna(method="ffill")
z_id= newdf['zone_id']
d_id= newdf['device_id']
s_id= newdf['site_id']
vst= newdf['visit_start_time']

for n,zone_id in z_id.iteritems():
    for o, site_id in s_id.iteritems():
        for m,device_id in d_id.iteritems():
            for p,visit_start_time in vst.iteritems():
                query=("""select site_id,business_day,zone_id,device_id,last_modified,duration,visit_start_time
                from shopper_journey.visits
                where zone_id=@zid and device_id=@did and site_id=@sid and business_day="2020-05-19" 
                and CAST(visit_start_time as DATETIME)="2020-06-03 01:41:13"
                group by site_id,business_day,zone_id,device_id,last_modified,duration,visit_start_time order by last_modified desc limit 100;""")
                query_parameters= [
                        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("zid","ARRAY",zone_id),
                        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("did","ARRAY",device_id),
                        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("sid","ARRAY",site_id),
                        #bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("st","DATETIME",visit_start_time)
                    ]
                job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
                job_config.query_parameters=query_parameters
                job=client.query(query,job_config=job_config)
                results=job.result()
                for row in results:
                    print("{}\t\t{}\t\t{}".format(row.duration,row.last_modified,row.visit_start_time))
```

Is data type provided correct for the line **"bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("zid","ARRAY",zone_id),"** ?
even i have provided as "STRING" but its not working ?

can some body please help with the issue

Comment: Can you remove the trailing comma from your list `query_parameters` and try it again?

Comment: If i remove comma its giving error

Comment: Is that the same error or another one?

Comment: I corrected my script & now its working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

updated my script & now its working fine.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

client = bigquery.Client()
df = pd.read_excel('16Junedata_03062020_80163767_action_03062020_80163767_2624_01.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet4')

zoneid = df['zone_id']
siteid = df['site_id']
deviceid = df['device_id']
starttime = df['visit_start_time']
duration = df['Duration']

zid = zoneid.tolist()
sid = siteid.tolist()
did = deviceid.tolist()
st = starttime.tolist()
dt = duration.tolist()

query="""select site_id,business_day,zone_id,device_id,last_modified,duration,visit_start_time from 
shopper_journey.visits where zone_id=@zid and device_id=@tid and site_id=@sid and 
business_day="2020-06-03" and visit_start_time=@st group by site_id,business_day,zone_id,device_id,
last_modified,duration,visit_start_time order by last_modified desc limit 1; """

for i in range(len(zid)):
        job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig\
                        (query_parameters =[
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("zid", "STRING", zid[i]),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("sid", "INT64", sid[i]),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("tid", "STRING", did[i]),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("st", "DATETIME", st[i])
                ])
        query_job=client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

        for row in query_job:
                print("{}\t\t\t{}\t\t{}".format(row.duration, row.last_modified, row.visit_start_time))
```